# Windows batch is not listing complete dir content

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, dir

I have a simple batch which saves the content of a specific folder and its subfolders to a text file.

Here's the original command. It is used on a Windows 7 environment.

```
dir I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\ /a /s /b > C:\out\LIST.txt
```

Problem: It creates the file and also lists most of the folders and files, BUT not all of them.

Here's an extract of the LIST.txt file.
The first 4 rows are missing the pdf file in the folder.

```
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\557487
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\557488
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\557489    
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\557669
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\552371\XXXX_641428_20141022_1604.zip
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\552372\XXXX_859038_20141022_1604.zip    
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\552379\Overview
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\552379\Overview\manuals_overview_1445_LIN.pdf    
I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\552381\LTBJ_886469_20141022_1800.zip
```

I can't figure out why. There are no filters, and other pdfs are listed. The files are not read-only. The user has full read/write permission on these directories.

Is it because the folder names are only numbers ?

I appreciate any help on this batch thing. Thank you !

Comment: I believe you need to be more explicit. Are you saying that the directories `...557487` etc contain .pdf files which are not being listed? What do you want? Just a listing of the `.pdf` files, or all files, or what? Nominally, the `/a` switch should be followed by a further qualifier. Without knowing what your target list is, we're guessing. Perhaps `attrib /s I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\*` may reveal something?

Comment: Thanks Magoo. Yes, in each of the folders there's 1 pdf file. Just like the rows below where the other pdf or the zip files are listed. The batch simply ignores the content of the numbered folders. I double checked again to see if the pdfs are really there, and they are.

Comment: All I can say is that it works fine for me. I created numbered subdirectories in my test area and tested with empty directories and directories with files in them. I used `/a` and omitted `/a`. All worked quite happily. I can only suggest a typo while searching your `list.txt` file with your text-editor.

Answer (score 0):

You command includes directory names so you see `I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN\557487` as its a directory.

To exclude add: `/a-d`

(Attribute-not-Directory)

Comment: Thanks Alex! The path name needs to be included. I nevertheless tried it and it just ignores the folders (does not list the pdf files).

Answer (score 0):

The bahaviour of `dir /s /b` command is to enumerate each level complete, so, in your case, the contents of `I:\Logistics\Hermes\1445\LIN` are listed. When this folder is completly enumerated, it starts to enumerate the contents of each of the subfolders, so, the contents of `552371` are enumerated before the contents of `557487` (in NTFS drives the elements are name ordered). Your missing pdf files will be some lines below, when the `557487` folder is reached.

Comment: Thanks MC ND, good point, I learned something! I now did a search on the whole txt file (has 4900 rows) and did not find the folder name again. So the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to MC ND's hint I finally found out that it's a memory issue. About 80000 files in 12000 folders is simply too much for dir. The saved text file simply stops randomly after about 5000 rows. Finally I split up the whole directory into subfolders.

Comment: Does the issue manifest itself only when you are redirecting the output to a file?

Comment: Tried it, and: yes. Could the txt file itself be the problem?

Comment: No idea. I tried reproducing a similar scenario on my machine: created 100,000 files, put them into 10,000 directories, then listed them all with a single `DIR /S /B` into a file – no issues. The output file's size was over 2.5 MB.